# Setting Configurations for convolutional layer in tensorflow js api 0.15.3

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a CNN that I have made in python using Keras API on tensorflow that I want to implement in JavaScript. But in tf for js API 0.15.3, I Cannot find the options to add strides and padding for convolutional layers.

My Python Code Looks like this.

```
X = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv0')(X_input)
```

In Js API ref.

> tf.layers.conv2d (args) function Source
>
> 2D convolution layer (e.g. spatial convolution over images).
>
> This layer creates a convolution kernel that is convolved with the layer input to produce a tensor of outputs.
>
> If useBias is True, a bias vector is created and added to the outputs.
>
> If activation is not null, it is applied to the outputs as well.
>
> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument inputShape (Array of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. inputShape=[128, 128, 3] for 128x128 RGB pictures in dataFormat='channelsLast'.
>   Parameters:
>
> args (Object)
>
> filters (number) The dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number of filters in the convolution).

Really Appreciate if anyone could help.
Should I use an old API like 0.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Found out that even though they haven't mentioned that we can give strides and paddings as an argument. We actually can, According to the source code.

```
constructor(rank: number, args: BaseConvLayerArgs) {
    super(args as LayerArgs);
    BaseConv.verifyArgs(args);
    this.rank = rank;
    if (this.rank !== 1 && this.rank !== 2) {
      throw new NotImplementedError(
          `Convolution layer for rank other than 1 or 2 (${this.rank}) is ` +
          `not implemented yet.`);
    }
    this.kernelSize = normalizeArray(args.kernelSize, rank, 'kernelSize');
    this.strides = normalizeArray(
        args.strides == null ? 1 : args.strides, rank, 'strides');
    this.padding = args.padding == null ? 'valid' : args.padding;
    checkPaddingMode(this.padding);
    this.dataFormat =
        args.dataFormat == null ? 'channelsLast' : args.dataFormat;
    checkDataFormat(this.dataFormat);
    this.activation = getActivation(args.activation);
    this.useBias = args.useBias == null ? true : args.useBias;
    this.biasInitializer =
        getInitializer(args.biasInitializer || this.DEFAULT_BIAS_INITIALIZER);
    this.biasConstraint = getConstraint(args.biasConstraint);
    this.biasRegularizer = getRegularizer(args.biasRegularizer);
    this.activityRegularizer = getRegularizer(args.activityRegularizer);
    this.dilationRate = normalizeArray(
        args.dilationRate == null ? 1 : args.dilationRate, rank,
        'dilationRate');
```